# cannot show a background:url from css in a php file

Tags: php, html, css

the problems is that i have this

```
<header id="header">

</div>
```

in the css i have this

```
#header{
    min-height:calc(100vh - 94px);
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(187, 139, 139),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),
    url(/images/image.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}
```

when i run from index.html the image.png is shown, but when i enter from the .php file it does not.

Comment: use background-image: url("~/images/image.png"); &  background-color: linear-gradient(rgb(187, 139, 139),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are having the wrong path for the file to access. Add a dot at the beginning or remove the first slash at the start. For example :

```
background: linear-gradient(rgb(187, 139, 139),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),
url("./images/image.png");
```

or

```
background: linear-gradient(rgb(187, 139, 139),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),
url("images/image.png");
```